# Get TRAMP working with cygwin sshd

Tags: tramp

I'm using both the latest Cygwin and the latest (released) Emacs. I'm trying to remote in from a Linux box to a Windows box running a Cygwin configured sshd.

I've added this line to the top of my `.bashrc` in Cygwin:

```
PS1='$ ' && return
```

Doing `ssh <own ip>` reveals that the prompt is indeed set to a single dollar sign. Unfortunately, TRAMP still hangs on.

> Tramp: found remote shell prompt

I would very much like to get this working. I don't really *know* what information is needed to fix this, but the machine is available and I'll do whatever anyone asks me.

EDIT: Here are the last few lines from the TRAMP debug buffer:

```
00:20:46.867625 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(^.*\(\(?:adgangskode\|contrase\(?:\(?:ny\|ñ\)a\)\|geslo\|h\(?:\(?:asł\|esl\)o\)\|iphasiwedi\|jelszó\|l\(?:ozinka\|ösenord\)\|m\(?:ot de passe\|ật khẩu\)\|pa\(?:rola\|s\(?:ahitza\|s\(?: phrase\|ord\|phrase\|wor[dt]\)\|vorto\)\)\|s\(?:alasana\|enha\|laptažodis\)\|wachtwoord\|лозинка\|пароль\|ססמה\|كلمة السر\|गुप्तशब्द\|शब्दकूट\|গুপ্তশব্দ\|পাসওয়ার্ড\|ਪਾਸਵਰਡ\|પાસવર્ડ\|ପ୍ରବେଶ ସଙ୍କେତ\|கடவுச்சொல்\|సంకేతపదము\|ಗುಪ್ತಪದ\|അടയാളവാക്ക്\|රහස්පදය\|ពាក្យសម្ងាត់\|パスワード\|密[码碼]\|암호\)\).*:? *\)\'" from remote shell
00:20:46.867729 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.867806 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.867940 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(^.*\(Connection \(?:\(?:clo\|refu\)sed\)\|Host key verification failed\.\|Login \(?:[Ii]ncorrect\)\|N\(?:ame or service not known\|o supported authentication methods left to try!\)\|Permission denied\|\(?:Sorry, try again\|Timeout, server not responding\)\.\).*\|^.*\(Received signal [0-9]+\).*\)\'" from remote shell
00:20:46.868026 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.868102 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.868206 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(^[^#$%>
]*[#$%>] *\)\'" from remote shell
00:20:46.868287 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.868360 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.868450 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Call `tramp-action-succeed'
00:20:46.868577 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
00:20:46.868671 tramp-process-actions (6) # 
root@192.168.0.132's password: 
Last login: Wed Dec 17 16:20:31 2014 from hexagon
$ 
00:20:46.868759 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
00:20:46.869100 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
00:20:46.869438 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Found remote shell prompt on `192.168.0.132'
00:20:46.869610 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-shell nil
00:20:46.869742 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell `/bin/sh'...
00:20:46.869956 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
00:20:46.870141 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-echo nil
00:20:46.870232 tramp-send-command (6) # exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 
00:20:46.870324 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
00:20:46.870429 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # chunksize nil
00:20:46.870531 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # last-cmd-time (21650 7646 870498 395000)
00:20:46.870630 tramp-send-string (10) # exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 
00:20:46.870719 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
00:20:46.870906 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.870989 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:46.871076 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:47.871626 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:47.871832 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:47.871994 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:47.872251 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:48.873309 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:48.873736 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:48.874024 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:48.874308 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:49.876580 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:49.877040 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:49.877350 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:49.877639 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:50.878858 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:50.880145 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:50.880448 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:50.880786 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:51.881874 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:51.883160 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:51.883507 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:51.883858 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:52.885235 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:52.885571 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:52.886065 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:52.886413 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:53.887413 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:53.887854 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:53.888154 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:53.888438 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:54.890273 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:54.890382 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:54.890455 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:54.890525 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:55.891045 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:55.891197 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:55.891312 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:55.891428 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:56.893634 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:56.894073 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:56.894368 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:56.894654 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:57.896874 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:57.897336 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:57.897650 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:57.897707 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:58.898896 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:58.899075 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:58.899160 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:58.899241 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:20:59.899977 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:20:59.900087 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:59.900167 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:20:59.900242 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:00.901654 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:00.914983 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:00.915349 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:00.915642 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:01.918396 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:01.918738 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:01.919128 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:01.919459 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:02.922186 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:02.922917 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:02.923275 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:02.923577 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:03.925233 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:03.925568 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:03.926084 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:03.926437 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:04.932720 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:04.933105 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:04.933397 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:04.933749 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:05.934743 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:05.935194 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:05.935509 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:05.935848 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:06.937524 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:06.937963 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:06.938262 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:06.938546 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:07.943139 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:07.943530 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:07.943793 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:07.944043 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:08.944492 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:08.944615 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:08.944697 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:08.944777 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:09.946517 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:09.947009 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:09.947325 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:09.947617 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:10.948612 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:10.948899 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:10.949396 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:10.949712 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:12.064294 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:12.064438 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:12.064543 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:12.064642 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:13.065006 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:13.065150 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:13.065257 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:13.065358 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:14.066901 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:14.067126 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:14.067359 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:14.067523 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:15.068126 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:15.068312 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:15.068465 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:15.068654 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:16.070011 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:16.070121 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:16.070198 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:16.070273 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:17.072215 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:17.072229 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:17.072461 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:17.072629 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:18.075270 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:18.075411 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:18.075514 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:18.075625 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:19.078041 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # 
00:21:19.078186 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:19.078293 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
00:21:19.078395 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* run
00:21:19.388384 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell `/bin/sh'...failed
00:21:19.389169 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for root@192.168.0.132 using ssh...failed
00:21:19.389481 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-truename nil
00:21:19.389695 tramp-flush-directory-property (8) # 
00:21:19.389949 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
00:21:19.390179 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
00:21:19.390617 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # vector [ssh root 192.168.0.132 ~ nil]
00:21:19.390846 tramp-process-sentinel (5) # Sentinel called: `#<process *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132*>' `killed
'
00:21:19.391118 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # *tramp/ssh root@192.168.0.132* (vector temp-file last-cmd-time)
00:21:19.391364 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-truename nil
00:21:19.391723 tramp-flush-directory-property (8) # 
00:21:19.513996 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
00:21:19.514284 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # [ssh root 192.168.0.132 nil nil] (first-password-request)
00:21:19.514578 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
00:21:19.514815 tramp-get-file-property (8) # / file-truename nil
00:21:19.514933 tramp-flush-file-property (8) # /
00:21:19.515035 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Interrupt received in operation (expand-file-name /ssh:root@192.168.0.132:~ nil)
```

The "interrupt" is me pressing `C-g` after a long time waiting.

Comment: Is the remote box using zsh?

Comment: Nope, it's a pretty stock Cygwin install, which uses `bash`.

Comment: I don't know where I got this `PS1` from, but this is what I have on my Arch VPS that helped TRAMP work: `if [[ $TERM == "dumb" ]]; then PS1='%(?..[%?])%!:%~%# ' fi`

Comment: @nanny sadly, that doesn't seem to help. I don't think the prompt is the issue.

Comment: @phils I'm actually talking about emacs running on linux, talking to a `sshd` running inside Cygwin on Windows, not the other way 'round.

Comment: @phils Ah, I can see that now. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The usual recipe is to apply `(setq tramp-verbose 10)` and to rerun the test. There will be a (longish) Tramp debug buffer, which shall tell what's up.

Comment: Added buffer contents to question.

Comment: According to the log, the login on the remote host succeeded. After that, Tramp has sent the command `exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh`. There's no output from that. What happens, if you connect to the remote host in a shell (outside Emacs), and apply that command?

Comment: Well, I get a `/bin/sh` (symlink to `bash`) with the prompt set to `#$ PS2=`, which I sense is not what they were going for. Is there an extra backslash?

Comment: Every char counts! There are two spaces between `$\ ` and `PS2=`.

Comment: Strange... there might be a bug in Cygwin clipboard handling. Anyway, the command does exactly what you'd expect it resets the prompts, the `ENV` and `HISTFILE` for bash.

Comment: Hmm, so I'm a little bit out of recommendations. The command sent by Tramp seems to be proper, but no response from Cygwin. Cygwin has always be problematic for Tramp. And I don't run MS Windows machines, so I cannot test myself.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but have you tried using tramp with the smb method? I have been using this for years to edit files located on a Windows machine from my Emacs session on Linux, and I am very happy with it. The only drawback might be, that you have to define a share to be able to access the files on Windows.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  I would suggest either asking this as a comment on the question or expanding it to provide a working example of using it this way.

Comment: As an example on how I use this, you can simply open a file by handing the following file to tramp: `smb:winUser%winDomain@host:/E$/` works, if E: is accessible as a share. I use bookmarks in conjunction with remote editing, which makes it easier to handle.